# Julia: Sort String Array by substring containment

Tags: julia

I've got some pretty ugly code to sort an array of strings that contains substrings of months.

So given:

```
months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
test = ["xxxFebxxx","xxxJanxxx","xxxAprxxx"]

function sortf(s)
    ix = 0
    for m in months
        if contains(s,m)==true
            return ix
        end
        ix = ix + 1
    end
    return size(months)[1] # in case substring not found
end

sort!(test,by=sortf)

# result should be ["xxxJanxxx","xxxFebxxx","xxxAprxxx"]
```

Whats the succinct Julia way to sort test by checking for the substrings in months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A succinct one-liner would be:

```
sort!(test,by=t->first(filter(x->contains(t,x[2]),enumerate([months;""])))[1])
```

Features used:

- `[months;""]` adds a dummy string at the end of `months` to reproduce moving a test-string with no month substring to end of list.
- `enumerate( )` attaches a number to each month to be extracted for use by `sort!`.
- `filter( )` goes over the collection of (number,month) pairs and searches for months in string. *Annoyingly `filter` alone might generate a warning and it can be replaced with `Iterators.filter` to avoid it*.
- `first( )[1]` gets the first (number,month) pair, stops `filter` and returns the month number.
- `sort!( ,by= )` is similar to line in question.

This performs the same calculation as in the question and also maintains the efficiency of the code in the question which explicitly short-circuits month searching and doesn't create too much intermediate variables.

Another route (à la @AlexanderMorley) would be to create the teststring x month matrix of searches. This is wasteful but is easy for the compiler to implement, so it is still fast:

```
test[
  sortperm(vec(mapslices(findfirst,contains.(test,reshape([months;""],1,:)),2)))
]
```

Comment: Thanks, had to replace filter with Iterators.filter as filter was deprecated in .6

Answer (score 1):

Could use some dot broadcasting to get this one-liner. To me its pretty readable but for sure wouldn't be very efficient.

`test[sortperm(findfirst.([contains.(x, [months; ""]) for x in test]), by=x->x[1])]`

*edited to reflect @DanGetz's comments*

Comment: Using `findfirst` is better here. Also, replacing `months` with `[months;""]` replicates no-month string behavior in question